# Maven Project is failing while running in Jenkins, but is working in Eclipse

Tags: maven, jenkins

[image: Error image]

maven project is getting failed but working in eclipse

Comment: You need to specify the Java version that you want to use in your POM.

Comment: Please submit the output as text and as image, so people find you error message using google. This is helpful for those who run into the same issue.

Comment: Please provide the exact maven command you run as well as your POM file.